# Split resultset with '|' and get the second value for each row

Tags: java, resultset

I have a Db column where I need to split the resultset by '|'.
I need to get the second value for each row that is populating

```
String example 
First row 34567|001
Second row 34545|002
```

I want to get 001 and 002 and I want to check whether I am getting 001 and 002.

```
String[] res = TBOOKER_TRD_INTFTable.getString("EXT_T_ID_C").split("|");
System.out.println(res);
String [] version=res.replaceAll("\\s", "").split("|",0);
List ves=Arrays.asList(version);
System.out.println(ves);
if(ves.contains("001") && (ves.contains("002")){
  System.out.println("version is correct");
}
```

Comment: You haven't asked a question. Please read [ask].

Comment: Sorry, I corected that. I just want to split with ('|')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just split the column value on pipe and then check the second value:

```java
boolean correct = false;
String[] parts = TBOOKER_TRD_INTFTable.getString("EXT_T_ID_C").split("\\|");
if (parts.length > 1) {
    if ("001".equals(parts[1]) || "002".equals(parts[1])) {
        correct = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I made some changes here and it worked for me.
   List<String> version = new ArrayList<>();
 version.add(parts [1].trim());

 if ((vs).length > 1)
            {
            System.out.println("My len" + vs.length);
            if ((Trdversion.contains(("001")) && (Trdversion.contains("002")))) {
                correct = true;
            }
            if(correct==true){
                System.out.println("version is available");
            }
            else{
                Assert.fail("version is not available");
            }

Answer (score 0):

refactor your code to this.

```
String result =" 34567|001";
String secondValue = result.split("\\|")[1];
if(secondValue.equals("001")||secondValue.equals("002")){
  //to something with the results
}
```

Comment: in resultset I have multiple value( two value for now)  
First row 34567|001 (34567 is random no which will change everytime)
Second row 34545|002 
How will this split String will store two values, I guess need to use list
secondValue = result.split("\\|")[1];

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through your result and then just split like below

```
let result = "34567|001"; //If its an array/object data just loop through it to get the result

console.log(result.split('|')); //['34567', '001']
let value = result.split('|')[1]) //001
```

once you got the value you can compare value with your data by using if-else or using in_array if you want to check from an array

Comment: in resultset I have multiple value( two value for now)  
First row 34567|001 (34567 is random no which will change everytime)
Second row 34545|002 
How will this split String will store two values, I guess need to use list
secondValue = result.split("\\|")[1];

Comment: that is not Java, but the question is only tagged with the [tag:Java] tag (e.g. `split()` does not take a `char` as argument; neither does it have `let`, and `|` is a special operator in most regular exprecssoin)

Comment: your response can be a set of array/object, just loop it to get the single data in result. Once you got the result you can split and get the second value by using ```result.split('|')[1])``` or ```result.split('|')[0])``` for first data. Then compare it to get the filtered result.